# Laravel pass parameter to email page

Tags: laravel-5

Under `Laravel 5` i'm trying to send mail for user with this below route :

```
Route::post('/sendEmailToUser', array(
    'as' => 'sendEmailToUser', function () {
        $data = \App\User::find(Request::input('user_id'));
        $cdata = array('message' => Request::input('message'), 'email' => $data->email);

        Mail::send('emails.custom_email_to_user', $cdata, function ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to($data['email'], 'Sample')->subject('Sample');
        });

        if (count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {
            Log::emergency("email dont send to user");
            return 0;
        } else {
            Log::info("email successfull send to user id" + Request::input('user_id'));
            return 1;
        }
    }
));
```

Result of `$cdata` is :

```
Array
(
    [message] => this is test mail
    [email] => myname@server.com
)
```

Unfortunately i get this error :

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\epay-pro\resources\views\emails\custom_email_to_user.blade.php)
```

My simple email page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Sample</h2>
        <div>
            {{$message}}
            {{ URL::to('www.epay.li') }}<br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change two things in your code and it will work.

1. **First : (choose how to use your variable $data)**

   You're using same variable `$data` sometimes as `array` and sometimes as `object` :

   **As object in :**

   ```
   $cdata = array('message' => Request::input('message'), 'email' => $data->email);
   ```

   **As array in :**

   ```
   $message->to($data['email'], 'Sample')->subject('Sample');
   ```

   Normally you should use it as `object` since `User::find` will return an object.
   **Note :** if you want to use it as array you have just to add `toArray()` after `find`.
2. **Second : (change variable $message name)**

   > **Note:** A $message variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows the inline embedding of attachments. So, you should avoid passing a message variable in your view payload.

   **[Source : Document laravel 5.1 - mail#introduction](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#introduction)**

   So you have to change `$message` variable name because Framework will consider it as an Object of class **Illuminate\Mail\Message**.

   - Take a look to the following discution about the problem **[Laravel Mailing Issue "Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Message could not be conv...](http://laravel.io/forum/08-14-2014-laravel-mailing-issue-object-of-class-illuminatemailmessage-could-not-be-converted-to-string?page=1)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While sending email $message variable seems to be conflicted with the laravels $message variable, i am not quite sure why. In your $cdata instead of `message` key use something else like maybe `$text`

```
$cdata = array('text' => Request::input('message'), 'email' => $data->email);
```